# first-child of grandparents

Tags: html, css

I have multiple divs inside a div.
I want the first h1 of the parent div to be underlined.
The problem with first-child is it looks at the parent div which in my case is the wrong parent.
For example:

```
        <div class="box">
            <div><h1>first h1 needs to be underlined</h1></div>
            <div>bla bla bla</div>
            <div>bla bla bla2</div>
            <div><h1>big bla bla bla but not underlined</h1></div>
        </div>
```

I want only the first h1 to be underlined but using `.box h1:firstchild` will result both h1 to be underlined.
Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
.box > div:first-child > h1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Note that the `first-child` is applied on the `div` and not the `h1` tag.

Comment: This will only work if `h1` is in the first `div`. What if it isn't?

Comment: @Moshe Learn to read the documentation (in this case, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors). It's the least you can do after someone showed you exactly how something is done.

Answer (score 5):

```
.box > div:first-of-type > h1:first-of-type{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you have multiple `h1` in first `div` it will underline only first `h1`. Just an add to Tims answer

**UPDATE JQuery Solution to underline h1 in any first div**

```
var h1Found = false;
$( ".box > div " ).each(function( index ) {

   $(this).find("h1").each(function(){
       if(h1Found) return false;
       $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline" );
       h1Found = true;
   })
});
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, then this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Tim yours is correct too. I just added further more. What Vucko is trying to say is if second div has h1 and not the first div. I am trying to work that out too.

Comment: @pratikwebdev you too may have misunderstood Vucko's point. @Vucko basically says "What if the first `<h1>` ever is in the second or third `<div>`?".

Comment: @ArmanOzak That is what i meant. I got vuckos point. Hence trying to figure out.

Comment: @pratikwebdev OK, then please note that **a pure CCS solution** for what he points at **does not exist at the moment**. The [Selectors Level 4 Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) suggests a `:has()` pseudo class which would let you check inner elements, but browsers do not have this functionality yet (and they may not have it anytime soon). Your answer will underline the first `<h1>` within the first `<div>` only. Try switching `<div><h1>first h1 needs to be underlined</h1></div>` with `<div>bla bla bla</div>` or `<div>bla bla bla2</div>` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @ArmanOzak I dont believe that OP is trying to achieve what Vucko mentioned. If so I will delete the answer and probably if you could post an answer with findings on `:has()` which will be helpful for future reference. I was just trying work on Vuckos point as a learning curve and also to make note to Tim that his answer was correct as well.

Comment: @pratikdev Your answer is as valid as (and probably better than) any other on this page, so no need to delete it. I will try to add an answer as you've suggested, but am currently mobile. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the first `<h1>` tag always in your first `<div>` then both answers given by **Tim** and **pratikwebdev** will work. However, as **Vucko** mentioned in a comment, if you have a situation like below, then CSS alone cannot help you.

```
<div class="box">
    <div>bla bla bla</div>
    <div><h1>first h1 needs to be underlined</h1></div>
    <div>bla bla bla2</div>
    <div><h1>big bla bla bla but not underlined</h1></div>
</div>
```

You see, **currently available CSS selectors work one-way only**, i.e. parent to child(ren) or element to next sibling(s), but not child to parent or element to previous sibling(s). So, once you select child(ren), there is no turning back to the parent level or once you select next sibling(s) there is no turning back to the current element. This, actually, is what makes CSS so fast.

The **Selectors Level 4 Draft** [suggests](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) a `:has()` pseudo class, which would let checking of inner elements before selecting next sibling(s). Nevertheless, browsers do not have this functionality yet, they may not have it anytime soon, and even when they do, it will be exclusive to the newest generation of browsers and will not be supported by the ones we currently have.

So, what can be done? Well, you can place a specific class directly on the first `<h1>` using the [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method or the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector of jQuery or your own **JavaScript** function. I personally don't think jQuery is necessary on something that easy.

**CSS:**

```
.underlined {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**JS:**

```
(function(H1s){
    var H1qty = H1s.length,
        grandParent,
        boxes = [];

    // Loop through H1s and add class name to first occuring H1
    for(var i=0; i<H1qty; i++){
        grandParent = H1s[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        if(grandParent.className === 'box' && boxes.indexOf(grandParent) < 0){
            H1s[i].className = 'underlined';
            boxes.push(grandParent);
        }
    }   

})(document.querySelectorAll('h1'));
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d4dbyL0g/).